# Retrieving values in an object in an array from local storage

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object

I have 2 webpages. One called Create An Event and the other Calendar Of Events. In Create An Event, a form is used to allow users' inputs. The inputs are then stored to local storage with the following function:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", docIsReady);
var CreateEvent;

function docIsReady() {
    CreateEvent = localStorage.getItem("CreateEvent");
    if (CreateEvent == null) {
        CreateEvent = [];
    } else {
        CreateEvent = JSON.parse(CreateEvent);
    }
}

function saveToStorage() {
    var one;
    var nameofevent = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var pList = document.getElementsByName("pos");
    var positions = [];
    for (i = 0; i < pList.length; i++) {
        positions.push(pList[i].value);
        console.log(pList[i].value);
    }
    //for (i=0; i<positions.length; i++){
    //console.log(positions[i].value);
    //}
    var venue = document.getElementById("venue").value;
    var date = document.getElementById("date").value;
    var starttime = document.getElementById("timeStart").value;
    var endtime = document.getElementById("timeEnd").value;
    var contact = document.getElementById("contact").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var desc = document.getElementById("desc").value;
    one = {
        "name": nameofevent,
        "pos": positions,
        "venue": venue,
        "date": date,
        "timeStart": starttime,
        "timeEnd": endtime,
        "contact": contact,
        "email": email,
        "desc": desc
    };
    CreateEvent.push(one);
    localStorage.setItem("CreateEvent", JSON.stringify(CreateEvent));
    return false;
}
```

I made CreateEvent an array so as to store the multiple inputs because there cannot be only one event created. Now, I need to display the NAME of the event in a table on Calendar Of Events. As its a calendar, the events will be sorted by the months. However, I don't know how to access the "date" and "name" value in each of the objects stored in the array. How do I retrieve the values in objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *index into* the array using `[]`:

```
var entry = CreateEvent[0]; // 0 = the first entry
```

...and then use the properties on that object:

```
console.log(entry.name);
```

---

Side note: You're free to do whatever you like in your own code, but FWIW, `CreateEvent` is an unusual name for this array for two reasons: 1. It starts with a capital letter, whereas in JavaScript the overwhelming convention is for data variables to start with a lower case letter. 2. It's a verb phrase ("create event"), but its value is a *noun* (an array of events). Typically lists and arrays are named with the name of what they contain, either in the plural or with a suffix like `list` or `array`. So in this case, `events` or `eventList` or `eventArray` would be more standard.

Comment: Thanks! However, is there a way I can use a for loop to go through all the entries?

Comment: Yes, or there are [lots of other ways as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476).